# increment sequence in PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, sequence, plpgsql

How to auto increment sequence number once for every run of a stored procedure and how to use it in the `where` condition of an `update` statement?

I already assigned a sequence number to the next value in each run, but I'm not able to use it in the `where` condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ops.mon_connect_easy()
   RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

declare
   _inserted_rows bigint = 0;
   sql_run bigint = 0;

   --assigning the sequence number to the variable 
   select nextval('ops.mon_connecteasy_seq') into run_seq_num; 


   -- use for selection iteration_id. this is hwere I'm getting stuck 

   update t_contract c
   set end_date = ce.correct_end_date, status='Active',
       orig_end_date =ce.correct_end_date
   from ops.t_mon_ConnectEasy ce
   where c.contract_id = ce.contract_id
     and run_seq_num = ??;
```

Comment: There is too little correct syntax in this to give a clear answer, but what keeps you from writing a variable name where you have the question marks?

Comment: No, my question is I have assigned a variable to increment the sequence number by one for each run of the stored procedure. but I'm not sure on how to use the assigned variable in the where clause, (denoted by question marks). Do you have any example of using a sequence variable in where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) advances the sequence automatically before returning the resulting value. You don't need anything extra. Just use the function in your query directly:

```
update t_contract c
set    end_date = ce.correct_end_date
     , status = 'Active'
     , orig_end_date = ce.correct_end_date
from   ops.t_mon_ConnectEasy ce
where  c.contract_id = ce.contract_id
and    iteration_id = nextval('ops.mon_connecteasy_seq');
```

Be aware that concurrent transactions *also* might advance the sequence, creating virtual gaps in the sequential numbers.

And I have a nagging suspicion that this might not be the best way to achieve your undisclosed goals.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have a stupid question now, How do I assign an iteration_id to a table?

Comment: @ShrinidhiVenkat: Please ask the new question as new *question*. Comments are not the place. Be sure to explain what an iteration_id is supposed to be / do exactly.